# Remove Common columns while Join in sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

On doing different joins using "a.*" the columns with same name are also getting adjoined to the main dataset. I need a way to either remove the duplicate columns or not join them at the first place.
It would be not be possible to indicate all the variables in the second table as I need a custom function for joining 2 datasets

Comment: you can just rename them so they have the same name, then they will not be duplicated i guess

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I believe this subsets the data set.

```
data <- data[ , !duplicated(colnames(data))]
```

So, essentially, this should work fine.

```
x <- x[ !duplicated(names(x)) ]
```